# Skipping a View in Navigation History

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

Is there any way to navigate with Prism (using RegionManager.RequestNavigate) whithout Pushing the view in Navigation History.

I want Navigate from `ViewA` to `ViewB` and From `ViewB` To `ViewC` without adding `ViewB` into `navigation history` such that when I call the `GoBack()` method from `ViewC` it takes me straight to `ViewA` skipping `ViewB`

Exemple :

```
I am in ViewA 
Call RequestNavigate(ViewB) -----> Show ViewB
Call RequestNavigateWithoutHistorisize(ViewC) ----> Show ViewC
Call GoBack() -------> Show ViewA
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of skipping the `frame` being added to the `Navigation Stack`, consider removing the `frame` from the `navigation stack` once it's `navigated.

For example, `ViewA` navigated to `ViewB` now remove last added element from `navigation stack` (which means ViewB gets removed). Navigate to `ViewC`.

Now if you see your Back stack would have `ViewA` and `ViewC` so when you call `GoBack()` it'll take you to `ViewA` directly.

Use the below code to remove that last entry into the `NavigationStack`

```
frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(frame.BackStackDepth-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `IJournalAware`
and return **false** for the `PersistInHistory()` method
`public bool PersistInHistory() => false;`
That's it

[PersistInHistory](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/30#issuecomment-344691680)